# Strange additions to querystrings when submitting HTML form

Tags: html, forms

A curious thing is happening to one of my internal websites that I am coding. I submit a form with some HTML "select/option" entries in it. These entries duly appear in the querystring of the target page when the form is submitted ... but with %0A%0D added to their end.

Sadly, this renders them unusable by the target page (they are supposed to be image (JPG) filenames. So "mypicture.jpg" becomes "mypicture.jpg%OA%OD", which doesn't work).

I've checked carefully; there are no %A0%AD entries anywhere in the source; they seem to be generated internally whilst in transit to the page they are submitted to ?

Just to be REALLY contrary, the same code works fine on another website (both websites are using the same source HTML files, stored on the same server, but just with different database connections,  so they are both LITERALLY using the same code).

Any thoughts about this aberrant and anti-social behavior ?

Comment: I think those are the codes for CR/LF.  How are you generating your querystring?

Answer (score 0):

'%A0' is the old way of how spaces are encoded in url(nowadays you tend to see '+' instead), since " " is not allowed, the same applies for '%AD'. Check your code to see if it is not leaving trailing whitespace for the url string.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it.. and it was NOTHING to do with HTML.

My form was populated by entries from my MySQL database.

It turns out that MANY (though not all) of those database entries - which represented image filenames (such as 'picture.jpg') - had somehow got a an invisible "/n" at the end of them (making them "picture.jpg/n"), which HTML converted into %OA%OD strings when they arrived at my ASP/HTML page.

I wrote a query to trim these all out from the database, and my application is now working properly, with no "%OA%OD" strings appended to the end of my querystrings.

Thanks for all your help :)